# Rails routes: Order of nested scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

so I have a route that is a bit more complex and I have an issue with the order of two nested scopes. Their order seems to be reversed. I want the most inner scope to be the last segment of the URL before the action. But it is the first.

**routes.rb**

```rb
namespace :customer do
  namespace :api do
    resources :products, only: [], param: :uid do
      scope module: 'products' do
        scope :buyer do
          post :set_to_waiting_list, to: 'buyers#set_to_waiting_list'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller:**

```rb
module Customer
  module Api
    module Products
      class BuyersController < Customer::ApiController
        def set_to_waiting_list
          # do stuff
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This gives me this route when running `rake routes`:

```
customer_api_product_set_to_waiting_list POST /customer/api/buyer/products/:product_uid/set_to_waiting_list(.:format) customer/api/products/buyers#set_to_waiting_list
```

But the URL I'm actually looking for is:

```
POST /customer/api/products/:product_uid/buyer/set_to_waiting_list
```

Reason is that this modifies the buyer and not the product. Also the buyer is fetched via the product uid (plus logged in user), so this URL format makes much more sense.

I don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

I'm still interested in the logic behind this. But for anyone looking for an solution, I just solved it with:

```rb
namespace :customer do
  namespace :api do
    resources :products, only: [], param: :uid do
      scope module: 'products' do
        post :set_to_waiting_list, path: 'buyer/set_to_waiting_list' to: 'buyers#set_to_waiting_list'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `nested` block so that the scope knows where to place the path prefix:

```rb
  namespace :customer do
    namespace :api do
      scope module: 'products' do
        resources :products, only: [], param: :uid do
          nested do
            scope :buyer do
              post :set_to_waiting_list, to: 'buyers#set_to_waiting_list'
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

`nested` is not documented, so I'm not sure if you should rely on this. As an alternative, you can add a `resource :buyers, only: [] {}` wrapper:

```rb
  namespace :customer do
    namespace :api do
      scope module: 'products' do
        resources :products, only: [], param: :uid do
          resource :buyer, only: [] do
            collection do
              post :set_to_waiting_list
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The route and controller are the same in both cases, but the URL helper is different:

```
customer_api_product_set_to_waiting_list
POST /customer/api/products/:product_uid/buyer/set_to_waiting_list(.:format)
customer/api/products/buyers#set_to_waiting_list
```

vs

```
set_to_waiting_list_customer_api_product_buyer
POST /customer/api/products/:product_uid/buyer/set_to_waiting_list(.:format)
customer/api/products/buyers#set_to_waiting_list
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12626